# How to check for a certain channel /role by a certain user

Tags: javascript, discord.js, commando

I want my bot to be able to check...

- If a channel my bot made matches a certain name...
  OR
- If a role my bot made matches a certain name...

THEN

The bot would return the action with the message `Mod mail is already activated here!`

**Here's my code**

```
var mg = message.guild

const mythings = mg.channels.filter(chane => chane.client.user.id === `595840576386236437` && chane.name === 'modmail' &&chane.type === `text`);
const mythings2 = mg.channels.filter(chane => chane.client.user.id === `595840576386236437` && chane.name === 'qanda' &&chane.type === `text`);
const mythings3 = mg.roles.filter(role => role.client.user.id === `595840576386236437` && role.name === 'ModMail');

console.log(mythings)

if(mythings)  return message.channel.send(`Rejected! There's possible fragments of modmail already set up here!`)
if(mythings2) return message.channel.send(`Rejected! There's possible fragments of modmail already set up here!`)
if(!mythings3) return message.channel.send(`Rejected! There's possible fragments of modmail already set up here!`)
```

**NOTE**

I am doing in this in ***discord.js-commando***, not ***discord.js*** so this is not in my index.js file so my only limitation is I can't refer to the client variable. Directory is *~/commands/extras/modmail.js/* instead of *~/index.js/* What I mean by this is I cannot start with the `client` variable because it will return to me as undefined, but something like `channel.client` would be allowed because it's defining the creator of the channel the messgae was sent in.

**What went wrong**

Here's what went wrong.

1. Bot doesn't find the channel channel
2. Bot returns

OR

1. Bot finds channel
2. Bot continues to make all the channels and roles.

I expect: Bot can search the guild for a channel that meets client.id AND name expectations and then return. Also, Bot can search the guild for a role that meets the owner (my(Referring to me being the bot)) id AND name and then return also.

The actual result is the bot returning when it's not supposed to, e.g. Bot returns when it doesn't find a channel when it is supposed to create one. (I cut out the code for it though)

Comment: "...my only limitation is I can't refer to the client variable." You're using `client` in the code snippet?

Comment: As in the client that initated the channel / role, not client as in referring to the `bot.login` and other actions the bot does in the `index.js` file. It means that I can't start with `client` because it is undefined but `chane.client` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) will always return a new Collection. Therefore, your first condition is always returning true and executing the `return` statement because the variable exists.

Either check the [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) property of the Collection, or use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) which will only return an element if the predicate function returns true.

Also, you'll have to go through the Audit Logs to check the *creator* of a channel. The instantiator is the client that *created the instance of the object*, which is not equivalent to actually creating the channel itself.

```js
// Async context (meaning within an async function) needed to use 'await'

try {
  const channelLogs = await mg.fetchAuditLogs({ user: '595840576386236437', type: 10 });
  const myChannels = channelLogs.entries.filter(e => e.target && ['modmail', 'qanda'].includes(e.target.name) && e.target.type === 'text');

  const roleLogs = await mg.fetchAuditLogs({ user: '595840576386236437', type: 30 });
  const myRole = roleLogs.entries.find(e => e.target && e.target.name === 'Modmail');

  if (myChannels.size !== 0 || myRole) {
    return await message.channel.send('Rejected! There\'s possible fragments of modmail already set up here!');
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Now my code checks for the name only. It ignores the `client.user.id`

Comment: @SomePerson Make sure that you have the right ID of the client that created the channel. It's being compared in both predicate functions so it can't be ignored.

Comment: I def. made sure that the correct id was there, for some reason it's still going based off of channel names.

Comment: @SomePerson Log `myChannels.first().client`.

Comment: Ok for some reason `.first()` was not working so I did `myChannels.client` and it returned the bot's info even though I was the creator of the channel.

Comment: @SomePerson The instantiator is *not* equivalent to the creator. Please check the answer's edit.